# depName is not defined

Tags: javascript

It tells me that depName is undefined.I am trying to iterate,just can see whats wrong with it.I am trying to get the most profitable department out of the array.

```
var salesData = [
{department : 'hardware', sales : 4500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 1500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 5500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 7500, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 2505, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 1540, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 1500, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 8507, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 8009, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 12000, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 18007, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 6109, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 7005, day : 'Friday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 12006, day : 'Friday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 16109, day : 'Friday'},
 ];

var depMap = {};
function mostProfitableDepartment() {
for (var i = 0; i < depName.length; i++) {
  var currentDep = depName[i]
}
console.log(currentDep);
}
mostProfitableDepartment(salesData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set a parameter on your function mostProfitableDepartment

```
// missing depName in function declaration
function mostProfitableDepartment(depName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < depName.length; i++) {
        var currentDep = depName[i];
        console.log(currentDep); // Was outside of the loop
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the name in your function declaration

```
function mostProfitableDepartment(depName) {
```